Find the natural numbers $x,y$ if $\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+2023}=y$
Question
Find the natural numbers $x,y$ if $\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+2023}=y$
my idea
$\sqrt{A}+\sqrt{B}=N$ where we noted $A=x-1$ and $B=x+2023$ and $N=y$
$\sqrt{A}=N-\sqrt{B}|^2$
$A=N^2+B-2N\sqrt{B}$
$\sqrt{B}=\frac{N^2+B-A}{2N}$ and because A,B,N are natural numbers we get that $\sqrt{B}$ is natural, so $B$ must be a perfect square. Similary we get that $A$ is a perfect square.
From here we can note $x-1=a^2$ and $x+2023=b^2$ which makes $a^2+1=b^2-2023$
$b^2-a^2=(b-a)(a+b)=2024=2^3*23*11$
Also $b-a<=a+b$ so from here we can analuse every case
Im not sure if my way of demonstrating that A and B are prefect sqaures is right. Also is there any more simple way of demonstrating it eithout that many cases. Hope one of tou can help me! Thank you!

You can use in the mathjax part of the answer \le or \leq(less/equal sign) for $\le$, and also the central dot \cdot is better typographically instead of the star, we compare $2^3\cdot 23\cdot 11$ with the product using asterisks...

Squaring gives
$$
x-1+x+2023+2\sqrt{(x-1)(x+2023)}=y^2.
$$
$$
2\sqrt{(x-1)(x+2023)}=y^2-2x-2022.
$$
Because the right hand side is a natural number, $(x-1)(x+2023)$ must be a perfect square, $s^2$.
$$
(x-1)(x+2023)=s^2.
$$
$$
x^2+2022x-2023=s^2.
$$
$$
(x+1011)^2-2023-1011^2=s^2.
$$
$$
(x+1011)^2-1024144=s^2.
$$
$$
(x+1011)^2 = s^2+ (2^2\times 11\times 23)^2.
$$
This means $x+1011$, $s$ and 1012 must be a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple .
Because $1011=3\times 337$ is coprime to $2^2\times 11\times 23$, we are looking for primitive Pythagorean Triples.

$\sqrt{x+2023}$ is very easy for $x=2$, it gives $45$ :-)

@R.J.Mathar: as far as I know, a comment can only contain up to $600$ characters. How did you succeed entering your comment?

@R.J.Mathar Thanks for your answer! But still, is my idea corect?

The idea used to proceed is fine. In the conditions of an Olympiad, for instance, people take care of each (missing) detail, so in our case maybe one should fill in some more words. I need an answer to show which points should be added, so the following would not fit as a comment. Points that may be important to mention in an Olympiad are marked in italics.
First of all, the direction of proof should be clear.
So let $x,y$ be natural numbers so that:
$$
\sqrt{\underbrace{x-1}_{\text{Notation: }A}}
+
\sqrt{\underbrace{x+2023}_{\text{Notation: }B}}=y
$$
This implies successively, as mentioned in the post,
$\sqrt A+\sqrt B=y$, then $\sqrt A=y-\sqrt B$, then $A=y^2-2y\sqrt B+B$, then (because of $y\ne 0$) $\sqrt B$ is a rational number. (Why is it a natural number? We can mention Gauss' lemma here on MSE, or something else which is equally laconic, but in the conditions of an Olympiad...) It can be uniquely written in the form $\sqrt B=m/n$ with relatively prime numbers $m,n>0$. Squaring gives $Bn^2=m^2$. So each prime factor of $n$ divides $m^2$, but since $n$ is relatively prime to $m$ there is no such factor, and we obtain $n=1$ (from the uniqueness of the factorization of a natural number as a product of primes). So $B$ is a perfect square.
Similarly, $A$ is a perfect square.
Write $A=a^2$, $B=b^2$ with $a,b\in\Bbb N$. And this implies (we further go in the same direction):
$$
(b-a)(b+a)
=b^2-a^2 = B-A=(x+2023)-(x-1)=2024=2^3\cdot 11\cdot 23\ .
$$
(The number on the R.H.S. has $(3+1)(1+1)(1+1)=16$ divisors, not so many in fact.)
The next step is to get a quick coverage of the cases obtained by splitting $2^3\cdot 11\cdot 23$ as a product of two factors. The two factors have the same parity, since they differ by $2a$, an even number. So we distribute the factor $2^3$ as $2^1$ to one of the factors $(a\pm b)$, and $2^2$ to the other factor. We consider now the factor containing the $2^2$, and all possibilities to donate to it the remained factors of ${\color{gray}2^3\cdot} 11\cdot 23$, so there are the following four possibilities only:

$2^2$ is multiplied by $1$, the two numbers $a\pm b$ are thus $2^=42$ and $2\cdot 11\cdot 23=506$, so we identify $b-a=2^2=4$, $b+a=2\cdot 11\cdot 23 =506$, which leads to $b=(506+4)/2=255$, $a=(506-4)/2=251$, $x=A+1=a^2+1=\bbox[yellow]{63002}$.
$2^2$ is multiplied by $11$, the two numbers $a\pm b$ are thus $2^2\cdot 11=44$ and $2\cdot  23=46$, so we identify $b-a=44$, $b+a=46$, which leads to $b=(46 + 44)/2=45$, $a=(46-44)/2=1$, $x=A+1=a^2+1=\bbox[yellow]{2}$.
$2^2$ is multiplied by $23$, the two numbers $a\pm b$ are thus $2^2\cdot 23=92$ and $2\cdot 11=22$, so we identify $b-a=22$, $b+a=2^2\cdot 23 =92$, which leads to
$b=(92+22)/2=57$,
$a=(92-22)/2=35$, $x=A+1=a^2+1=\bbox[yellow]{1226}$.
$2^2$ is multiplied by $11\cdot 23$, the two numbers $a\pm b$ are thus $2^2\cdot 11\cdot 23=1012$ and $2$,
so we identify $b-a=2$, $b+a=2^2\cdot 11\cdot 23 =1012$, which leads to
$b=(1012+2)/2=507$,
$a=(1012-2)/2=505$, $x=A+1=505^2+1=\bbox[yellow]{255026}$.

We went all the time in one direction, the converse was not really in the focus. This is fine, but then we must (and want to) check the above numbers. And indeed:

For $x=63002$ we have $\sqrt(63002-1) + \sqrt(63002+2023) = 251 + 255 = 506$.
For $x=2$ we have $\sqrt(2-1) + \sqrt(2+2023) = 1 + 45 = 46$.
For $x=1226$ we have $\sqrt(1226-1) + \sqrt(1226+2023) = 35 + 57 = 92$.
For $x=255026$ we have $\sqrt(255026-1) + \sqrt(255026+2023) = 505 + 507 = 1012$.


Manipulating the equation to get rid of the radicals:
$$\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+2023}=y$$
$$(\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x+2023})^2=y^2$$
$$x-1 + 2\sqrt{(x-1)(x+2023)} + x + 2023=y^2$$
$$2\sqrt{x^2 + 2022x - 2023} = y^2 - 2x - 2022$$
$$4(x^2 + 2022x - 2023) = (y^2 - 2x - 2022)^2$$
$$4x^2 + 8088x - 8092 = y^4 - 2xy^2 - 2022y^2 - 2xy^2 + 4x^2 + 4044x - 2022y^2 + 4044x + 4088484$$
$$y^4 - (4x + 4044)y^2 + 4096576 = 0$$
By the Rational Root Theorem, if $x$ and $y$ are integers, then $y$ must be a factor of $4096576$, i.e., in the set $\{1, 2, 4, 8, 11, 16, 22, 23, 32, 44, 46, 64, 88, 92, 121, 176, 184, 242, 253, 352, 368, 484, 506, 529, 704, 736, 968, 1012, 1058, 1472, 1936, 2024, 2116, 2783, 3872, 4048, 4232, 5566, 5819, 7744, 8096, 8464, 11132, 11638, 16192, 16928, 22264, 23276, 33856, 44528, 46552, 64009, 89056, 93104, 128018, 178112, 186208, 256036, 372416, 512072, 1024144, 2048288, 4096576\}$.
Solving for $x$ in terms of $y$ gives
$$x = y^2 - 4044 + \frac{1024144}{y^2}$$
Filtering out the candidate solutions that result in non-integer values of $x$, we are left with:
$$(x, y) \in \{(2, 44), (2, 46), (1226, 22), (1226, 92), (63002, 4), (63002, 506), (255026, 2), (255026, 1012)\}$$
But it turns out that only 4 of these satisfy the original equation.
$$\boxed{(x, y) \in \{ (2, 46), (1226, 92), (63002, 506), (255026, 1012) \}}$$

From your method:
$$A = x - 1 \in \{ 1, 1225, 63001, 255025 \} = \{ 1^2, 35^2, 251^2, 505^2 \}$$
$$B = x + 2023 \in \{ 2025, 3249, 65025, 257049 \} = \{ 45^2, 57^2, 255^2, 507^2 \}$$
Which confirms your conjecture that both radicands must be perfect squares.

Hint:
As $b-a+ b+a=2b, b\pm a$ have the same parity which must be even as is $2024$
$$b^2-a^2=2024$$
$$\implies\dfrac{b+a}2\cdot\dfrac{b-a}2=506$$
WLOG $b>a>0\implies \dfrac{b-a}2<\dfrac{b+a}2\implies \left(\dfrac{b-a}2\right)^2<\dfrac{b+a}2\cdot\dfrac{b-a}2=506<23^2$
$\implies \dfrac{b-a}2\le22$
Now the factors of $506$ below $23$ are $?$

Thank you so much for your answer! But still... is my idea corect?

@IONELABUCIU, obviously $$A, B$$ must be perfect squares, but how to proceed from there?

@labhattacharjee I told that we can take cases...(a+b,b-a)=(2024,1), (1012,2),(506,4), (253,8), (184,11),(92,22),(88,23),(46,44) and analyse each of them
